# How to run Jetty on IKVM?

Tags: jetty, ikvm

I am new in jetty. I am trying to run Jetty with IKVM. However, it throws exception. I am not sure what should I do.

```
alex@AlexUbuntu:/usr/share/jetty$ ikvm -jar start.jar
5 [main] INFO org.mortbay.log - Logging to org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:179)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:508)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:439)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:99)
Caused by: cli.System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'org.apache.xerces.util.NamespaceSupport' from assembly 'ikvm_dynamic_assembly__40326550, Version=2011.611.1039.16726, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:517)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:333)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:320)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlParser.setValidating(XmlParser.java)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlParser.<init>(XmlParser.java:68)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.initParser(XmlConfiguration.java)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:105)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:958)
    ... 5 more
```

It seems that I need to install some external libraries in order to make it works. But what should I need to install.

The environment is fresh and clean:

```
Ubuntu 11.04
IKVM 0.40.0.1
Java 1.6.0_22
Mono 2.6.7
```

**Update on 28 June 2010**

I think I make it works. But I haven't try loading .NET classes in jetty. By the way, I used a dirty method that I replaced `/usr/bin/java` and `/usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm/java` with `ikvm.exe`. So everytime when I type `java` that actually is IKVM.

I will try to load .NET classes in jetty. But I am not familiar with jetty so I may take sometime.

**Update on 1 July 2010**

I have tried to load a .NET class. However, finally I got an error message.

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /hello/servlet. Reason:

    ikvmstub generated stubs can only be used on IKVM.NET
Caused by:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ikvmstub generated stubs can only be used on IKVM.NET
    at cli.CSharpClass.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at HelloServlet.doPost(HelloServlet.java:28)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you run Jetty with 'java -jar start.jar'?

I suspect you need at least a few base JAR files for jetty even if it's classloader dynamically loads everything that is needed. It looks like it is failing in the log initialization.

Add the xerces JAR file to the classpath when running IKVM.

```
 ikvm -cp .:xerces.jar -jar startup.jar
```

**Update**

I just looked through `jetty.sh` and there are a few things the script file sets up. You'll need to go through that file and determine what you need out of it, or replace all the instances of java with ikvm and be aware that Jetty also uses tools.jar

Comment: `java -jar start.jar` can run. `ikvm -cp .:xerces.jar -jar startup.jar ` gets the same exception. Does `jetty.sh` means `/etc/init.d/jetty` file?

Answer (score 0):

The jar files that you generate with ikvmstub are only for the java compiler and not for the runtime. The java compiler can nor work with .NET dlls. For the runtime you need to use the dlls directly.

We use the jetty without problems with IKVM but we use a newer version 0.46. The simplest is you build all jar files in one step with a shared classloader. See the [ikvm wiki](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=ClassLoader) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I don't quite understand what I need to do because I am new in IKVM and Jetty. Could you share the steps to me? Thanks you very much.

Comment: I can not answer it without spending many time because the jetty is only a small part of the project. First the jetty must be without problems. Then you search all jar files that you need and then compile it with one line.